# Sharing Office 365 folder with OneDrive Personal

Tags: office365, onedrive

I have a privat Office 365 account. Now I have a folder and want to send it to another person.

This person has only a OneDrive personal account.
So I sent a link to this address.

He can open the link in the browser. But he can't add this folder into his OneDrive folders.
So he can't use the Explorer to manage the files.

PS: It is not about my own fiels.
I have some friends using only OneDrive personal.

What I am doing wrong?
Or is there a further link or explanation about the differences. Between Office 365 and OneDrive personal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend a OneDrive Personal Account with an existing Office 365 license](https://superuser.com/questions/1761383/extend-a-onedrive-personal-account-with-an-existing-office-365-license)

Comment: No. I have some friends using only OneDrive personal.
So if I send files to them, they can only access the files via the browser...
That should be the answer here... changed the quesiton.

Comment: Did he go to [OneDrive Online](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/signin/Login/) > Shared with you > Select the folder you shared with him > Click "sync"?

Comment: The folder of the Office 365 doesn't appear in this section.