# Extend a OneDrive Personal Account with an existing Office 365 license

Tags: office365

I have an existing Office 365 family license.

Also I have an existing OneDrive account associated with my email address.

When I open the OneDrive App I get the offer to purchase any extended storage.

Is it possible to extend my OneDrive personal account with the existing Office365 license?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft 365 includes OneDrive, but you cannot merge it with your
personal account.

From
[How do I merge my OneDrive for home with my OneDrive for work or school ?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-i-merge-my-onedrive-for-home-with-my-onedrive-for-work-or-school-85fe5779-dbc8-4c81-abdb-214a3a7)

> Microsoft OneDrive personal account and a Microsoft 365 work or school account cannot be merged, but they can be used side by side.

You may continue to use the two OneDrive accounts side by side,
or transfer the files from one account to the other and abandon it.

Nothing forces you to use the OneDrive of Microsoft 365.
You may continue to use your personal OneDrive.

Comment: I don’t believe there is a separate subscription plan for just OneDrive. I believe the only subscription plans that provide additional OneDrive storage space are Office 365 subscription plans. However, as you point out, you don’t have to subscribe for that additional storage, since a free amount is offered.

Answer (score 0):

> > Is it possible to extend my OneDrive personal account with the existing Office365 license?

No, these are 2 different licenses, but as harrymc said, you can migrate your personal OneDrive files to the one included in Office 365 subscription.